# How to edit Contact Form 7 action URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am attempting to change the action URL to an external URL to send my post data to. I am currently using the below snippet to do so. I am attempting to send the POST data to a google app-script. I have an issue where if a user forgets to fill out a required field, the POST data still gets sent which typically ends up having duplicate entries when they submit the form again with the required field fixed.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');
function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url($url)
{
    global $post;
    $id_to_change = POST ID;
    if($post->ID === $id_to_change)
        return 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/REDACTED';
    else
        return $url;
}
```

I would like to change this so it only sends the POST data to that URL after Contact Form 7 validates all of the fields and is OK to submit. I am also skipping email.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default CF7 is sending the data via an AJAX POST request to the current URL (which is your wordpress installation), then validates the data, then sends the emails if validation passed otherwise returns the appropriate error message(s). By changing the form action to some external URL, the data entered by the user will never reach your Wordpress installation, so CF7 cannot perform any validation or send emails.

I suggest you do not change the form action and let CF7 do its job, but intercept after validation but before sending any emails. This way you get the validated form data, which you can then *forward* to wherever you like:

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'forward_cf7_post_data' );

function forward_cf7_post_data($contact_form) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if($submission) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $post_data = http_build_query($posted_data);
        // You can now POST that data to anywhere you like
        // e.g. using file_get_contents or using cURL
        $opts = ['http' =>
            [
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content' => $post_data
            ]
        ];
        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        $result = file_get_contents('https://script.google.com/macros/s/REDACTED', false, $context);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Side benefit: Other CF7 plugins (like Flamingo) keep on working this way.